# How to run tests and get coverage in a golang application with a particular structure?/

Tags: unit-testing, go

Let's say my golang project has a directory structure like this:

```
├── go.mod
├── main.go
├── pack
│   └── runner.go
└── test
    └── pack
        └── runner_test.go
```

How do I run the tests and get the coverage?
Simply running `go test -cover` does not work with this directory strucure. I get `[no test files]`. It only works when `runner_test.go` and `runner.go` are in the same directory.

Comment: Note that your "structure" is absolutely non-idiomatic and considered bad practice by basically ever gopher: Test (the *_test.go files) should live in the same folder than the code. Go is not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended for the code and its tests to be in the same directory, because they're typically in the same package.

Moreover, you can run *all tests* in a module from its root directory with `go test ./...` -- this will run tests of all packages in the module.

I'd modify your code structure slightly to be:

```
├── go.mod
├── main.go
├── pack
    └── runner.go
    └── runner_test.go
```

Assuming the code in `runner.go` is in package `pack` (note that in Go the package name is the containing dir's name).

---

See [Testing](https://golang.org/doc/code#Testing) in the official "How to Write Go Code", and [Add a test](https://golang.org/doc/tutorial/add-a-test) in the Go tutorial.